Why is Brownian motion normally distributed?
I'm reading the book Probability Theory: A Concise Course (Rozanov), and in the chapter where the normal distribution is first discussed, Brownian motion was given as an example. Here are the assumptions:

The particle moves only along the x-axis.
The particle moves only at the times $t = n\Delta t$, $n=0,1,2,...$
Suppose the particle is at position $x$ at time $t$. Then ,regardless of its previous behavior, the particle moves to either of the two neighboring positions $x + \Delta x$ and $x - \Delta x$ ($\Delta x > 0$) with probability $\frac{1}{2}$.

We also have that $S_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} X_k$ where $X_k$ is Bernoulli, and $S_n^* = \frac{S_n - E(S_n)}{\sqrt{Var(S_n)}} = \frac{S_n - np}{\sqrt{npq}}$ since $S_n$ is binomial.
For $X(t)$ denoting the position of the particle at time $t$, assume $X(0)=0$ and after $t = n\Delta t$ seconds, the particle undergoes $n$ displacements of amount $\Delta x$, where $S_n$ is the number of displacements to the right.
Then after many arguments, we get that $X(t) = S_n^*\sigma \sqrt{t}$, where $\sigma^2 = \frac{(\Delta x)^2}{\Delta t}$. Here is the part I do not understand:
Applying the De Moivre-Laplace Theorem and passing to the limit $\Delta t \to 0$ while holding $\sigma$ constant (so that $\Delta x \to 0$), we find that the random variable $X(t)$ describing the one-dimensional Brownian motion satisfies the formula
$P(x' \leq \frac{X(t)}{\sigma \sqrt{t}} \leq x'') = \lim_{\Delta t \to 0}{P(x' \leq S_n^* \leq x'')} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{x'}^{x''}{e^{-x^2/2}} dx$.
The De Moivre-Laplace Theorem, as stated in the book, is:
$\lim_{n \to \infty}{P(x' \leq S_n^* \leq x'')} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}} \int_{x'}^{x''}{e^{-x^2/2}} dx$.
I don't see how one follows from the other. I thought that $S_n^* = \frac{X(t)}{\sigma \sqrt{t}}$. Any insights would be appreciated!

The author should be distinguishing between $X(t)$, the position at time $t$ of Brownian motion, and $X_n(t)$, the position at time $t$ of a particle meeting assumptions (1-3). The idea is that $X(t)$ is an idealized version of $X_n(t)$, as $\Delta t\to0$.
The argument holds fixed a time $t>0$, and seeks to write down what $X_n(t)$ looks like. After $n$ steps (such that $t=n\Delta t$) of size $\Delta x$, the particle has undergone $S_n$ displacements to the right, and therefore has undergone $n-S_n$ displacements to the left, so the overall position of the particle is
$$X_n(t) = \Delta x[S_n-(n-S_n)] =\Delta x[2S_n-n] =\Delta x\sqrt n\left(\frac{S_n-\frac n2}{\frac12 \sqrt n}\right)=:\Delta x\sqrt nS_n^*$$
where $S_n$ is a binomial($n, p=\frac12$) random variable and $S_n^*$ is its rescaled version.
Now if we fix $\sigma>0$ and take $\Delta x:=\sigma\sqrt{\Delta t}$, then
$$\Delta x\sqrt n:=\sigma\sqrt{\Delta t}\sqrt n=\sigma\sqrt t$$ since $t=n\Delta t$. Conclude:
$$\frac{X_n(t)}{\sigma\sqrt t}=S_n^*.$$
If we consider the behavior of $X(t)$ to be the limiting behavior of $X_n(t)$ as $\Delta t\to0$, then
$$P\left(x'\le \frac{X(t)}{\sigma\sqrt t}\le x''\right)
=\lim_{\Delta t\to0}P\left(x'\le \frac{X_n(t)}{\sigma\sqrt t}\le x''\right)=\lim_{\Delta t\to0}P\left(x'\le S_n^*\le x''\right).$$
Since $n\Delta t=t$ is constant, we have $n\to\infty$ whenever $\Delta t\to0$, so apply De Moivre-Laplace to the RHS.
